# Offset Array Order in Javascript for use with Backstretch plugin

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let us say I have an array of images. Now I want to always have the **same order**, but a different starting position. I can force an index in Backstretch, but not before it has already launched the first image, so naturally, I would like to just offset the array.

```
['1','2','3','4']
```

Should become, depending on random variable

```
['3','4','1','2'].
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TJ Crowders answer is excellent but in case of preserving order here is my 2 cents

```
var arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4']; //your source array

var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*arr.length); //get the random
var part = arr.splice(0, rand); //split from start to that number
arr = arr.concat(part); //concat back to push the part to the end for the order to be preserved.
//get your item arr[0]
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm3nk/)

Comment: What's the advantage of that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP says he want to preserve the order of the array.

Comment: @ PSL: Doh! He did! I completely missed that.

Comment: Worked like a charm, just used array_splice, and array_merge instead for PHP. It is so obvious, my mind was somewhere else completely. Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that shift the elements by randomly generated n number.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nghns/

```
function randShiftArr(arr) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rand; i++)
        arr.unshift(arr.pop())
    return arr;
}

var arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var shifted = randShiftArr(arr);
alert(shifted.join());
```